# Python High Performance Computing

Tags: python, multithreading

C and Fortran have traditionally been used for High Performance Computing (Stuff to do with Linear Algebra, PDE solvers and the like). I have noticed some projects based in NumPy and SciPy coming up in HPC. Some people suggest that Python (with modifications of course) could be the next HPC language. Obviously, Python may not **replace** these languages but maybe add a friendly wrapper around them. Are there any resources for proving/disproving this hypothesis? In other words, **Should budding HPC researchers add Python to the list of languages they are proficient in? If yes, Why ?**

NOTE: This is not a discussion question wherein I am asking you to weigh the pros & cons of languages. Neither am I asking you whether (in your opinion) Python is good for HPC. I am asking for references (in the form of academic papers, workshops or benchmarks) which have investigated such claims.

Comment: you can always just write python extensions in c...

Comment: "could be the next HPC language" is hardly a hypothesis that can be proved or disproved...

Comment: Oh, you edited. Yes, HPC researches should be apt in as many languages as possible (as any programmer should). OCaml is also nice, Scala is, other languages are. Any more questions?

Comment: I don't know. I've seen people using Python scripts where Bash scripts are more than sufficient (In HPC domain but not directly linked to parallel programming). Am I wrong or are they? Portability isn't a concern.

Comment: Python can be used on HPC projects... or any type of project.  They may be using Python for their build, test or analysis systems.  Just not the high performance parts. =)

Comment: @sholsapp, so is it a "must-have" for HPC researchers?

Comment: @Nunoxic: I don't know what you are trying to tell me. Using the right language for the job is useful in every domain, not just HPC. Still, this question is overly broad and it's not clear (at least to me) what's actually asked here. Of course it can't hurt to learn Python or any other language you like, it will surely make you a better programmer overall. **EDIT:** No, it's not a "must-have". Nothing is.

Comment: @sholsapp: I don't quite agree. It can be used for anything except maybe for the actual computational parts, but as far as I know, these absolutely critical parts usually only take few percents of the whole code base.

Comment: @Niklas B. that's what I said. Exactly.

Comment: @sholsapp: I think it can be used for even more than the build, test or analysis systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the [global interpreter lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) is the biggest reason why Python (and other dynamic languages (not all)) won't be used for HPC.  It would take considerable work to remove the GIL from Python.

Because the GIL forces developers to use processes for parallel computation (which require IPC or shared memory), Python isn't an ideal language for HPC.  [This](http://www.scientificcomputing.com/High-Performance-Development-with-Python.aspx) post is an interesting read in regards to GIL, Python, Python alternatives (like Jython and IronPython), and HPC.

Comment: There exist alternative implementations like IronPython which don't have the GIL. Also, there exist a lot of dynamic languages that don't have a GIL as well.

Comment: That's true -- IronPython and Jython don't have a GIL, but aren't those really different languages that just "look" like Python?  P.S. Which languages (out of curiosity)?

Comment: IronPython has everything CPython has, so how is it a "really different language"? Examples of languages without GIL are, well, IronPython, IronRuby, Ruby on Rubinius (I think), Scala, OCaml, Haskell, ...

Comment: I mispoke.  I'm not saying they're "really different languages" -- they're identical!  I'm saying that when you boil it down to the interpreter or compiler, they're different.  C++ has everything C has.  Is it a different language?

Comment: No, C++ doesn't have everything C has, so it's a bad example. Also in the case of C/C++, the language itself differs, rather than the runtime environment/available libraries. And for the domain of this question, the actual implementation is irrelevant, if you know Python, you also know IronPython and vice versa.

Comment: I think usage of MPI for Python would solve problem of GIL. Different processes, different locks.

Comment: @sholsapp: True. If you decide to learn a new language, you will first have to learn the syntax, then the built-in language features, then the relevant parts of the standard library. All this is independent of the actual implementation, and it's only after you've managed to grasp all this that you have to decide on a particular framework.

Comment: @sholsapp you are confusing "language" with "implementation".  IronPython is an implementation of Python.. as is CPython (the reference implementation), PyPy, etc.

Comment: @Corey: Boom. You're right. =)  I still think it matters.